# Output web page source code in Visual C++

Tags: html, c++, libcurl

I'm a C++ beginner and I want to save/output a web page html source code from an input URL to then read the downloaded .html using ifstream

I tried to use libcurl but it seems too hard for me to even include the library. Is there a workaround in getting a webpage source code downloaded without libcurl?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Enter the link: ";
    string link;
    cin >> link;
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", link.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

}
```

I've managed to open the webpage from a given URL but I have no idea on how to do 2. and 3.:

1. Open the webpage from link [DONE]
2. Download the source code (.html)
3. Close the webpage

Comment: ***I tried to use libcurl but it seems too hard for me to even include the library*** My advice is spend a few hours to days and learn how to do this.

Comment: After hours of searching, the only way was using libcurl. I managed to get it to work on VS2019 by following this easy tutorial: https://tcno.co/TroubleChute/info/curl-vs2019/